# Unable to change Python interpreter on Spyder for mac

Tags: python, data-science, spyder

I have Spyder 4.2.1 installed on macOS Catalina.

It comes with an embedded Python interpreter by default. The problem is that it doesn't recognize the packages I've installed (like pandas), so I want to change the interpreter.

This is the interpreter I want to use:

```
$ which python
> /Users/user/.asdf/shims/python
```

if I change it on `Spyder -> Preferences -> Python interpreter` -> `Use the following Python interpreter` -> `/Users/user/.asdf/shims/python` I receive the following error `Invalid file path: /Users/user/.asdf/shims/python` when clicking `Apply`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html) it should be here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Comment: this is default Python that comes with mac. I want to point to the Python installed with asdf (https://github.com/danhper/asdf-python)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

Pointing to the following bin works (don't forget to restart Spyder after changing):
`/Users/user/.asdf/installs/python/3.9.1/bin/python3.9`

Then I had to install `spyder-kernels` to make the Spyder console work:

`python -m pip install spyder-kernels`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't inspect a DataFrame on Variable explorer, I get:

```
Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.

The error message was:
KeyError('pandas._libs.interval')
```